# What are the present technologies used to develop web applications for faster development

Tags: web, web-deployment, webdeploy, web-deployment-project, web-architecture

I would like to build a web application from scratch. How do i choose the technologies? It should be easier and faster. 
The application have to develop for my own use. How do i make decision.

Please help me?

Comment: The best tools always depend from what are you trying to to..

Answer (score 1):

Back-end developers should develop and maintain functional logic and operations of a website or a software. You should have programming skills in languages such as Java, Python, PHP, Ruby or another high-level programming language used for back end.

Database creation, integration and managing with tools such as MySQL, MongoDB, SQLite etc. Some knowledge on back-end frameworks would definitely help (Laravel, Django, Ruby on Rails).

Your role would be to create and maintain application logic, databases, API integrations, content management system (CMS) development. You should know a thing or two about security and hack prevents as well.

You would also perform testing and debugging of back-end.